# Quill.js 2.0.0 image-resize plugin availability

Tags: javascript, quill

I just wanted to know if someone has already updated quill to it's latest 2.0.0rc version and is using the plugin image-resize for it.

Before it was simply initialisable by using it like that:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        imageResize: {
          displaySize: true
        },
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
          ['image','link', 'video']
        ]
    },
    placeholder: 'Write something...',
    readOnly: false,
    theme: 'snow'
  });
```

With 2.0.0rc it says, it is not able to import it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS SCRIPT FOR BEFORE 2.0**

```
https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.min.js
https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.snow.css
https://cdn.rawgit.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/3411c9a7/image-resize.min.js
```

**USE THIS FOR AFTER 2.0**

```
    <link
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      integrity="sha384-7kltdnODhBho8GSWnwD9l9rilXkpuia4Anp4TKHPOrp8/MS/+083g4it4MYED/hc"
      href="http://lib.baomitu.com/quill/2.0.0-dev.3/quill.snow.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      integrity="sha384-MDio1/ps0nK1tabxUqZ+1w2NM9faPltR1mDqXcNleeuiSi0KBXqIsWofIp4r5A0+"
      src="http://lib.baomitu.com/quill/2.0.0-dev.3/quill.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/scrapooo/quill-resize-module@1.0.2/dist/quill-resize-module.js"></script>
```

Comment: That does not solve it. Console tells me 'quill Cannot import modules/imageResize. Are you sure it was registered?'